# Rabbitmq consumer not consuming messages

Tags: python, kubernetes, rabbitmq, pika

I have 120 kubernetes pods that connects to the same rabbitmq queue and consume messages (same python code in all).
the consumers pods triggers up when there are messages in the queue.

I have thousands of messages in the queue, but not all consumers get messages.
If I restart the pod, sometimes it starts to consume messages and sometimes it's not.

on the rabbitmq management, I see 120 active consumers with status = up. everything looks ok. but not all consumers actually work.

what can be the problem? or how can I check further?

Comment: I think you need to check the logs from the Pod (maybe enable debug) and check if they are waiting for the messages.

Comment: thank you for your comment. i did enable debug, there is nothing useful there...